# Problem in puting text under \only in tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

In slide 2, I want to put a "text" (not "node") "Hello" (as mentioned in the code) to the left of the node "O.D.E soln". Not able to do that

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Intuition: Continued...}
  \tikzstyle{format} = [draw, thin, fill=blue!20]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> Recall the proof of tracking lemma  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex', thick]
      \path[use as bounding box] (-5,0.5) rectangle (10,-2);
\only<1>{
      \path[->]<1-> node[format] (link) {Algorithm};
}
\only<2->{ 
     % Want to put "Hello" to the left of the node "O.D.E soln" 
      \path[->]<2-> node[format, below of=link] (incl) {O.D.E soln.:};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \item<3->  Solution
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `\node [left=of incl] {Hello};`? (Requires `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`, see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386))

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I could not understand. Can you please put that in my code ? Thanks. Is \node correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'ODE-soln' node you have named `incl`. You can place a `\node` to the left of it with

```
\node[left=of incl] {Hello};
```

which requires `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`. `\node` is a shorthand for  `\path node`.

Below is a complete example. I also changed `below of=` to `below=of`, because of what is described in [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386), and I changed from `\tikzstyle{name}=[<options>]` to `\tikzset{name/.style={<options>}}` as the latter is recommended. Finally, your two existing nodes I changed to `\node[format] {...};`.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,arrows,shapes}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Intuition: Continued...}
  \tikzset{format/.style={draw, thin, fill=blue!20}}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> Recall the proof of tracking lemma  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex', thick]
      \path[use as bounding box] (-5,0.5) rectangle (10,-2);
\only<1>{
      \node[format] (link) {Algorithm};
}
\only<2->{ 
     % Want to put "Hello" to the left of the node "O.D.E soln" 
      \node[format, below=of link] (incl) {O.D.E soln.:};
      \node[left=of incl] {Hello};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \item<3->  Solution
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```